# Windows Forms Events in PowerShell - Sender and EventArgs in PowerShell

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell, events

How can I correctly handle events of Windows Forms controls in PowerShell and use `Sender` and `EventArgs`?

What's the equivalent of following C# code in PowerShell?

```
button.MouseClick += (sender, e) => {
    MessageBox.Show($"{((Control)sender).Name} \n {e.Location}");
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To correctly handle events of a Windows Forms control in PowerShell and take advantage of `Sender` and `EventArgs` you can use either of the following options:

- Define `sender` and `e` parameters for script clock
- Use `$this` and `$_` Variables

**Define `sender` and `e` parameters for script block**

Like lambda event handlers in C#, you can define `param($sender,$e)` for the script block:

```
$button.Add_MouseClick({param($sender,$e)
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(" $($sender.Name) `n $($e.Location)")
})
```

**Use `$this` and `$_` Variables**

`$this` is the sender of the event and `$_` is the event args:

```
$button.Add_MouseClick({
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(" $($this.Name) `n $($_.Location)")
})
```

Comment: is it possible to have another parameter `param($sender, $e, $is='MouseClick')`