# Where to find documentation about add_<eventname>(<scriptblock>) like add_click, add_shown using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm creating windows form.

I'm looking for documentation about this code :

```
$bouton.Add_click($boxtext)
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate(); $textbox.Focus()})
```

and if it exists other code using $form.Add_

I use Windows Powershell ISE but i haven't completion for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the below links:

1. [How-to-build-a-form](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-build-a-form-in-7e343ba3)
2. [Creating_GUIs_in_Windows_PowerShell_1.0_with_WinForms](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_GUIs_in_Windows_PowerShell_1.0_with_WinForms)

Comment: how to obtain a list of all add_<eventname> in powershell if it's possible

Comment: Need to know the proper Dot Net class to get all of them. I need to do some rnd to get that.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to this question is lacking info that those new to PowerShell and Windows forms and controls may find useful.

You can find detailed information and documentation for events in Windows forms and controls through both PowerShell code and online [webpages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

This script:

1. Provides info for the ListView control.
2. Creates, and opens, ListView_Add_Events.txt which list all "Add_" methods for adding events for the ListView control.
3. Opens a GridView showing all events for ListView and their definitions.

```
### 3 ways for making System.Windows.Forms available to the script ###
## Only works in PowerShell 5.1 ##
# using assembly System.Windows.Forms
## Works in PowerShell 5.1 and 7.x ##
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
## Works in PowerShell 5.1 and 7.x ##
# [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$ListView = [Windows.Forms.ListView]@{
}

$ListView | Get-Member -Force | Where-Object { $_.Name.StartsWith('Add_','CurrentCultureIgnoreCase')} | Out-File ListView_Add_Events.txt
.\ListView_Add_Events.txt
$ListView | Get-Member -MemberType Event | Select-Object -Property Name, Definition | Out-GridView
```

Further more, Microsoft does provide detailed documentation for the ListView control - though the focus is on C# and not PowerShell.  To start with, we want documentation that matches our .NET version that we are using.  According to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.2):

> Windows PowerShell 5.1 is built on top of the .NET Framework v4.5

Doing a little searching I was able to find the [events for .NET Framework 4.5.2 version of ListView in this page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.5.2#events)

Once you find the online documentation, you can easily find documentation for other controls, or even the [events for Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=netframework-4.5.2#events), using then navigation panel on left side of the webpage, and you can also select the desired version of .NET using the **Version** selector near top left of the page.

**One final note:** I found this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130615/4190564) useful for adding/creating events.