# Capture Windows Form close event in Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have a windows form. When I click on the close (X) button of the Windows Form Control Box, I want to display a message or may be do something.

Below is the code:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles() 

$frmTest = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$frmTest.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(640,480)
$frmTest.MaximizeBox = $False
$frmTest.ShowDialog()
```

When the user clicks on the Close (X) button, I want to display a message box:

```
$choice = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Are you you want to exit?','TEST','YesNo','Error')
switch($choice)
{
    'Yes'
     {
         $frmTest.Close()

     }
}
```

I found this article: [Message on Form Close](https://www.sapien.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=10518), but I am not sure how to use this. Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event to capture is [`Closing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing?view=netframework-4.8) event of the form which has an event argument which allows you to cancel the event. To learn how to use event args in PowerShell, you may want to take a look at [Windows Forms Controls Events in PowerShell - Use Sender and EventArgs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130615/3110834).

**Example**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text ="Test"
$form.Add_Closing({param($sender,$e)
    $result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(`
        "Are you sure you want to exit?", `
        "Close", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNoCancel)
    if ($result -ne [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Yes)
    {
        $e.Cancel= $true
    }
})
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
```

Comment: The code has been tested and works as expected. Yes, intellisense will not show autocomplete for the event. But it's the way to handle the event.

Comment: Just one more question: If I have a button named as Cancel, how can I call the Form Closing Event Method?

Comment: No worries. You don't call event handler, instead you do something which results in raising the event which will be handled by the event handler, for example $form.Close() will raise Closing event of $form.

Comment: Cool, No problem.

Comment: Sure, I will be glad to 

Comment: If I have one more button and I want to close the form but without any msgbox, how to do this? Also how to disable the close button? Really appreciate

Comment: For hiding the close button, You can set `$form.ControlBox` to false. To prevent a showing the dialog when trying to close using a specific button, setting a flag can help. Then in closing event, check if that flag is set, don't show the message box.