# Powershell GUI strip menu item OnClick event

Tags: powershell, winforms, user-interface

I am practicing building a GUI for an application I built and am struggling a little bit with stripMenus. For my 3rd menu item I am trying  to list my socials and OnClick have it open up youtube for example. I am just not completely familiar with the syntax of it and it is shockingly hard to find documentation regarding this online.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.StartPosition='CenterScreen'

$MenuBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip
$fileToolStripMenuItem        = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
$editionToolStripMenuItem     = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
$socialToolStripMenuItem      = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem
$YtToolStripMenuItem      = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem

$Form.Controls.Add($MenuBar)

$MenuBar.Items.AddRange(@(
$fileToolStripMenuItem,
$editionToolStripMenuItem,
$socialToolStripMenuItem))

$fileToolStripMenuItem.Name = "fileToolStripMenuItem"
$fileToolStripMenuItem.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(35, 20)
$fileToolStripMenuItem.Text = "&File"

$editionToolStripMenuItem.Name = "editionToolStripMenuItem"
$editionToolStripMenuItem.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(51, 20)
$editionToolStripMenuItem.Text = "&Edition"

$socialToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(@($YtToolStripMenuItem))
$socialToolStripMenuItem.Name = "socialToolStripMenuItem"
$socialToolStripMenuItem.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(67, 20)
$socialToolStripMenuItem.Text = "&Socials"

$YtToolStripMenuItem.Name = "YtToolStripMenuItem"
$YtToolStripMenuItem.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(152, 22)
$YtToolStripMenuItem.Text = "&YouTube"
```

**Below is where I would like to learn the syntax to execute powershell commands**

```
function OnClick_YtToolStripMenuItem($Sender,$e){
    #powershell -w h -NoP -NonI -Exec Bypass Start-Process https://www.youtube.com"     
    [void][System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Subscribe to my youtube")
}
$YtToolStripMenuItem.Add_Click( { OnClick_YtToolStripMenuItem $YtToolStripMenuItem $EventArgs} )

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Simply `Start-Process 'https://www.youtube.com'` should be enough to open youtube using your default browser :)

Comment: that is what i currently have in my code above and tried, however with that code there my entire menu bar actually just dissapears. If you uncomment that line it will disappear the GUI wont even open

Comment: You currently have `powershell -w h -NoP....` commented, I'm just saying `Start-Process URL` should be enough

Comment: [Windows Forms Events in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130615/3110834)

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to get rid of the *event args* as they were not needed. The following snippet is how I was able to get it working:

```bash
$YtToolStripMenuItem.Name = "YtToolStripMenuItem"
$YtToolStripMenuItem.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(152, 22)
$YtToolStripMenuItem.Text = "&YouTube"
function OnClick_YtToolStripMenuItem() {
    Start-Process 'https://www.youtube.com/iamjakoby?sub_confirmation=1'
}
$YtToolStripMenuItem.Add_Click({ OnClick_YtToolStripMenuItem })
```