Dynamically detecting selected radio button in PowerShell form
I've searched Google and this site thoroughly and haven't been able to find the right solution to this.  Any help will be appreciated.
I have trimmed this down to only the problem sections of my full script for posting.  This script produces a form that displays a dynamically created list of radio buttons inside a group box.  The script uses an external file to load the item list but for this I just added a hard list.
My goal is that each time any radio button is selected a function runs that populates another part of the form (not included) with data.  Until OK is clicked the radio buttons can be randomly selected which changes the data the function loads.  I've tried numerous examples of scanning for changes but cant get any to work.  If I add explicit click events things work fine but I want it dynamic since the number of items in the item list determines the final size of the form.
Some examples I've tried are commented out at the bottom of the script.
As listed below the form works with explicit event handlers and prints the selected radio button text to the screen.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
$ScreenSize = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_DesktopMonitor | Select-Object ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight)

If ($ScreenSize.Count -gt 1){  #--[ Detect multiple monitors ]--
    # More than 1 monitor detected...
    ForEach ($Resolution in $ScreenSize){
        If ($Null -ne $Resolution.ScreenWidth){
            $ScreenWidth = $Resolution.ScreenWidth
            $ScreenHeight = $Resolution.ScreenHeight
            Break
        }
    }
}Else{
    $ScreenWidth = $Resolution.ScreenWidth
    $ScreenHeight = $Resolution.ScreenHeight
}

$SiteList = @()
$SiteList += "site 1"
$SiteList += "site 2"
$SiteList += "site 3"
$SiteList += "site 4" 
$SiteList += "site 5"
$SiteList += "site 6"
$SiteList += "site 7"
$SiteList += "site 8"

Write-host $SiteList.Count

#--[ Define Form ]--------------------------------------------------------------
[int]$FormWidth = 750
If ($SiteList.Count/2 -is [int]){
    [int]$FormHeight = ((($SiteList.Count/2)*20)+255)   #--[ Dynamically Created Variable for Box Size (Even count) ]--
}Else{
    [int]$FormHeight = ((($SiteList.Count/2)*23)+255)   #--[ Dynamically Created Variable for Box Size (Odd count) ]--
}

[int]$FormHCenter = ($FormWidth / 2)   # 170 Horizontal center point
[int]$FormVCenter = ($FormHeight / 2)  # 209 Vertical center point
[int]$ButtonHeight = 25
[int]$TextHeight = 20

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$Form.minimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($FormWidth,$FormHeight)
$Form.maximumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($FormWidth,($FormHeight+80))

$CbLeft = 17
$CbRight = 163
$CbHeight = 30
$CbVar = 20
$CbBox = 145

$Count = 0


$Range = @()
$GroupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
While ($SiteList.Count -gt $Count) {
    #--[ Left Checkbox ]--
    Remove-Variable -Name "RadioButton$Count" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $Left = new-object System.Windows.Forms.radiobutton -Property @{
        Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size($CbLeft,$CbHeight)
        Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size($CbBox,$TextHeight)
        Text = $SiteList[$Count]
        Enabled = $true 
    }
    
    New-Variable -Name "RadioButton$Count" -value $Left
    $LeftBox = Get-Variable -name "RadioButton$Count" -ValueOnly
    $Range += $LeftBox
    $Count++

    #--[ Right Checkbox ]--
    Remove-Variable -Name "RadioButton$Count" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $Right = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.radiobutton -Property @{
        Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size($CbRight,$CbHeight)
        Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size($CbBox,$TextHeight)
        Text = $SiteList[$Count]
        Enabled = $true 
    }
    
    New-Variable -Name "RadioButton$Count" -value $Right
    $RightBox = Get-Variable -name "RadioButton$Count" -ValueOnly
    $Range += $RightBox
    $Count++ 

    $CbHeight = $CbHeight+$CbVar
}

write-host "site count " $Count

$GroupBox.Location = '35,95'
$GroupBox.size = '310,135'
$GroupBox.text = "Locations"
$GroupBox.Controls.AddRange($Range)
$form.controls.add($GroupBox)

$BoxLength = 100
$LineLoc = 30
$InfoBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InfoBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size((($FormHCenter-($BoxLength/2))-10),$LineLoc)
$InfoBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($BoxLength,$TextHeight) 
$InfoBox.Enabled = $False
$InfoBox.TextAlign = 2
$Form.Controls.Add($InfoBox) #>

$BoxLength = 100
$LineLoc = $FormHeight-77
$CloseButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CloseButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($FormHCenter-($BoxLength/2)-75),$LineLoc)
$CloseButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size($BoxLength,$ButtonHeight)
$CloseButton.TabIndex = 1
$CloseButton.Text = "Cancel/Close"
$CloseButton.Add_Click({
    $Form.Close()
    $Form.Dispose()
})
$Form.Controls.Add($CloseButton)

$ProcessButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ProcessButton.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(($FormHCenter-($BoxLength/2)+55),$LineLoc)
$ProcessButton.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size($BoxLength,$ButtonHeight)
$ProcessButton.Enabled      = $false #true
$ProcessButton.Text = "Execute"
$Form.Controls.Add($ProcessButton)

$event1={
    if ($RadioButton0.Checked){$InfoBox.Text = "You selected 1"}
    if ($RadioButton1.Checked){$InfoBox.Text = "You Selected 2"}
    if ($RadioButton2.Checked){$InfoBox.Text = "You selected 3"}
    if ($RadioButton3.Checked){$InfoBox.Text = "You Selected 4"}
    if ($RadioButton4.Checked){$InfoBox.Text = "You Selected 5"}
    if ($RadioButton5.Checked){$InfoBox.Text = "You Selected 6"}
    if ($RadioButton6.Checked){$InfoBox.Text = "You Selected 7"}
    if ($RadioButton7.Checked){$InfoBox.Text = "You Selected 8"}
}

$RadioButton0.Add_Click($event1)
$RadioButton1.Add_Click($event1)
$RadioButton2.Add_Click($event1)
$RadioButton3.Add_Click($event1)
$RadioButton4.Add_Click($event1)
$RadioButton5.Add_Click($event1)
$RadioButton6.Add_Click($event1)
$RadioButton7.Add_Click($event1)
#>

# Where-Object {$PSItem -is [system.windows.controls.radiobutton] -and $PSItem.IsChecked} | Select-Object Name

<#
$Form.Controls | Where-Object { $Item -is [System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton] } | ForEach-Object { 
        $Item.Add_Click({ 
        If (-Not $ProcessButton.Enabled){
            $ProcessButton.Enabled = $True
        }
    }) 
}#>

$Form.topmost = $true
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()


You can add an event handler, the same for all RadioButtons, in the while loop. Then check what RadionButton ($this) has been clicked when the event is raised (avoid subscribing to the same event twice)

Why do you want to scan when the click event is much better method.  You do not need in event 1 all the if statements. The event has a parameter which gives you the button object that was clicked.  Then you can get the text of the button object.  A radio button has two parameters 1) Sender 2) e (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#examples).  So your event1 can be $event1={param($sender,$e)}   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51130595/windows-forms-events-in-powershell-sender-and-eventargs-in-powershell

Thanks to both of you for your replies.  By reviewing both I was able to find an option that works.  I wasn't aware that inside a control's event handler the "$this" automatic variable refers to the control itself and can be used to identify various things within the control.  I'm not a .Net programmer so I find many of these things by examining other scripts, but I am learning.  I also found some great resources to help find these answers on my own.
In any case I was able to replace the left and right button creation in the original while loop as shown:
While ($SiteList.Count -gt $Count) {    
    #--[ Create Radio Boxes ]--
    Remove-Variable -Name "RadioButton$Count" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    New-Variable -Name "RadioButton$Count" -value $RadBox
    $RadBox = Get-Variable -name "RadioButton$Count" -ValueOnly    
    $RadBox = new-object System.Windows.Forms.radiobutton
    $RadBox.Text = $SiteList[$Count]
    If (0,2,4,6,8 -contains "$Count"[-1]-48) {
        $RadBox.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size($CbLeft,$CbHeight)
        $Count++
    }Else{
        $RadBox.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size($CbRight,$CbHeight)
        $CbHeight = $CbHeight+$CbVar
        $Count++
    }
    $RadBox.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size($CbBox,$TextHeight)
    $RadBox.Enabled = $true 
    $RadBox.Add_Click({
        $InfoBox.Text = $This.text
        $ProcessButton.Enabled = $true
    })
    $Range += $RadBox
}

This dynamically generates the side-by-side button list within the group box and displays the radio button name in the infobox.  That was my ultimate goal so as to be able to extract the number of the button selected.  Additionally, I was able to cut the loop code in half with some of the other things I read.

For anyone interested I've posted the final script up on GitHub at Site-Check script
